# TThe application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

When I'm trying to run my App In Android 14 I got error like this

[image]

[image]

05/10 17:33:46: Launching 'app' on Pixel 6 API UpsideDownCake.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

```
List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\debugger\AndroidStudioProjects\android14\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Comment: It's saying the device/emulator you're trying to run it on is a lower version of Android than your `minSdk` of *API 26*. What's the API level of the AVD you're running in that emulator? You've named it *API UpsideDownCake* (aka Android 14) but is that actually what it's using? And are you using the latest preview version of Android Studio, which it says is required here (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/get)?